# Iterating over bidimensional Java arrays

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

```
public static List<Vertex<Integer>> petersenGraph() {
    List<Vertex<Integer>> v = new ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        v.add(new Vertex<Integer>(i));
    }

    int[][] edges =
    {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {3,4}, {4,3}, {4,0}, {0,4},
    {5,6}, {6,5}, {6,7}, {7,6}, {7,8}, {8,7}, {8,9}, {9,8}, {9,5}, {5,9},
    {5,0}, {0,5}, {6,2}, {2,6}, {7,4}, {4,7}, {8,1}, {1,8}, {9,3}, {3,9}};

    for (int[] e : edges)
        v.get(e[0]).successors().add(v.get(e[1]));

    return v;
}
```

I understand everything up to the point where there's the for which iterates over the edges. What is exactly is going on there?

edit: why are they accessed using `e[0]` and `e[1]`? is `e[0]` the first number and `e[1]` the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, that's ugly.

edges is a bidimensional array, so it is an array of int arrays. In the actual definition, it is an array of pairs.

The line for (int[] e: edges) simply means that in each iteration, e will become a different array of ints, so in each iteration it is a different pair.

Then, e[0] represents the first item in the pair and e[1] represents the other.
So the first coordinate is used to look up a vertex, and then something happens and the second coordinate gets added in. Without seeing vertex or knowing the algorithm, it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The multi-dimensional array `edges` is effectively an "array of arrays."  The `for` statement is extracting one element from `edges` at a time, and each element of `edges` is an `int[]`.

So the first time through the loop, e will be `{0, 1}`.  The second time it will be `{1, 0}`.  The third time it will be `{1, 2}`.  And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia page on the graph it's creating is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph.

From the look of it, edges in the graph are represented by the Vertex.successors collection, and the **edges** array is used to construct the graph, using the first index as the *from* node and the second index as the *to* node for each edge.

This would also explain why each pair is followed by its opposite, eg {0,1}, {1,0}, as the Peterson Graph is undirected, so connections between nodes must be represented in both directions.