# Comparing two 2D double arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compare, double

I have an assignment where I parallelize matrices, and have to compare my parallelized matrix with one that has been solved sequentially. I tried using Double to compare the two, but this is apparently not allowed - I must use the primitive double. So I found this code snippet here to help compare them:

```
float error = 0.000001 * second;
if ((first >= second - error) || (first <= second + error)) {
   // close enough that we'll consider the two equal
   ...
}
```

And it works, but I need to flip it so I can run through my 2D array and return false if the two are *not* equal. I don't think I understand what it does well enough, so I don't get how to flip it trigger on mismatches instead. Can anyone help? Or if anyone has a different solution, that would also be great.

Comment: I think you want `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: I tried that now, by adding a value in one of the matrices that I know to be faulty, but replacing || with && doesn't pick up on it, and ends up not triggering at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over bidimensional Java arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486197/iterating-over-bidimensional-java-arrays)

Comment: So you're trying to find the values that ARE within range, or the ones that AREN'T?  The comment in your code suggests that your condition should be `true` for the values that ARE within range.  If you want it to be `false` for the values that ARE within range, you should have `if (first >= second + error || first <= second - error )` - that is, swap the `+` and the `-`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified better in my post. Your solution worked though, thank you so much!